# Nextjs with Typeorm trying to migrate giving error

Tags: next.js, typeorm

I am using nodejs typeorm in nextjs framework

When I am trying to migrate I get error

Please find the below screenshot

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "Cannot create property 'users-hp-anaconda3-python3-exe' on string '{\"users-hp-anaconda3-python3-exe\":\"\"}'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "c:\\laragon\\www\\shop\\yarn-error.log".
```

[image]